# Performing queries for multple search phrases in psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, vector

I want to perform a query but searching for more than one key word like

```
Select "Accession_Number" from Works where to_tsvector("Description") @@ to_tsquery('music') OR @@ to_tsquery('chair') OR to_tsquery('garb');
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your DDL looks like something like this:

```
create table Works
(   
    "Accession_Number" serial,
    "Description" text,

    primary key ("Accession_Number")
);

insert into Works 
  ("Description") 
values 
  ('lorem ipsum dolor garb sit'),
  ('brown fox chases music'),
  ('hello do you remember me chair'),
  ('what is this Description');
```

For searching multiple columns for a specific keyword you have multiple options.

The following query shows the use of [POSIX Regular Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

```
select "Accession_Number", 
       "Description"
from Works
where "Description" ~ '(music|chair|garb)';
```

You can also use [LIKE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) or [SIMILAR TO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILAR-TO-REGEXP).